# The adjugate of a hermitian matrix is hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I want to prove that if a matrix $A$ is hermitian, i.e. $\bar A^t=A$, then so is its adjugate $\text{adj}A$.

My proof goes as follows. $A$ is hermitian, so $\bar a_{ji}=a_{ij}$. We have $\overline{[\text{adj}A]_{ji}}=(-1)^{i+j} \det \bar A_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j} \det A_{ji}= \text{adj} A_{ij}$, where $A_{ij}$ denotes the matrix obtained from $A$ by removing its $i$th row and $j$th column. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. I would suggest that you add a step to explicitly note that $\overline{\det(A_{ij})} = \det \bar A_{ij}$. Also, this step should probably be justified; it suffices in this case to note that the determinant is a polynomial (on multiple variables) with real coefficients.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I noted this fact without explicitly mentioning it